# C# Using Directive for SqlCommand and Sql Connection as well as System.Web.UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, nuget

I am using the Nuget packages to build my Visual Studio 2015 Solution and I am struggling to find a few of the correct packages. What specific package must I call to receive the following:

SqlCommand() Class
SqlConnection() Class

Using System.Web.UI  ( I have found the extensions for System.Web but can't find the UI portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlCommand and SqlConnection are both part of the System.Data.SqlClient namespace, which is part of the .NET Framework. So using NuGet is not necessary - it can be used by adding a "framework" reference to System.Data.

System.Web.UI is included as part of the System.Web assembly which you say you've already added.

Comment: Thank you! @abrown